# Git Flow Production Hotfix Commit

Tags: git, merge, branch, conflict, hotfix

We are new on git. We used SVN for repository management. Now we are using Git Flow and we have a 
confusion about hotfixes. When we have bug from production we create a new branch from master named 1.1.X For example. After resolving bug we want to carry this fix to develop or release branch how should we do that? We must use cherry pick? We don't want to pull develop branch to 1.1.X branch because we want allign with production on a branch. If we meet with a conflict, How should we resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Burak,

The **hotfix** creates a branch from your actual ***master*** to correct anything (bug or whatever). You can create a hotfix branch using this command line:

```
git flow hotfix start <name_of_hotfix>
```

After commit the changes you need to finalize the hotfix using this command line:

```
git flow hotfix finish <name_of_hotfix>
```

It will merge the hotfix branch into your ***master*** and your ***develop*** branches.

> If you have anymore doubts you can access this link to clarify:
>   https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/